# Login form in PHP not working or pulling from MySQL database

Tags: php

```
<?php
include 'db.php';
session_start();

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") 
{

if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
$loginEmail = $_POST['email'];

}

$sql = "SELECT UserEmail FROM User WHERE UserEmail = '$loginEmail' ";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if ($count == 1) {
// User doesn't exist

header("location: home.html");

}
 { // User exists

    header("location: index.php");
}
  }
mysqli_close($conn);
    ?>
```

Code either takes me to index page or home page, but does not check to see if email is in MySQL database. It is either not recognizing the email in the database or something else is going on.

Comment: what if you run the SQL requests manually ? can you print the error message ? did you establish the `$conn` connection ?

Comment: *"Code either takes me to index page or home page"* - Which one is it? It can't be either. It's either one or the other. There isn't enough code here neither.

Answer (score -1):

Try to change this one

```
$sql = "SELECT UserEmail FROM User WHERE UserEmail = '$loginEmail' ";
```

to

```
$sql = "SELECT UserEmail FROM User WHERE UserEmail = '".$loginEmail."'";
```

your query will be like

```
select UserEmail FROM User WHERE UserEmail = Email@yahoo.com
```

It should be

```
select UserEmail FROM User WHERE UserEmail = 'Email@yahoo.com'
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't see any code that would validate the email. You are just checking to see if a User records exists in the database with an email address that matches what is being passed via `POST`.

```
session_start(); // this should come before anything else
include 'db.php';

if(isset($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['email'])) {

    $loginEmail = $post['email'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM User WHERE UserEmail = '" . $loginEmail . "'"; // select all (*) records with a matching email
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result); // number of matching records

    if($count == 1) {

        // Record was found

    } else {

        // Record was not found OR more than one record was found

    }

} else {

    // $_POST['email'] is not set OR is empty

}

mysqli_close($conn);
```

Unrelated to your question: you should really be using [PDO](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo) and prepared statements for your database queries, especially since you're passing your `$_POST` data directly to your SQL statement ([dangerous!](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp)).